# Posting memes, photos and jokes ‘is’ not or ‘are’ not?

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Which one of these two sentences is correct:

> 1. Posting lame memes, photos and jokes IS not gonna make you funny.
> 2. Posting lame memes, photos and jokes ARE not gonna make you funny.

Comment: Both are found. Formal analysis requires _is_, as the subject is singular "posting"; but (particularly in speech) many people are swayed by the more recent plural items and say _are_.

Comment: Yes, but in a similar example, a comment was that "the subject is not 'posting' but 'memes, photos and jokes'. That made (still makes) me rethink what is right.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is correct. I parse it in my head as "[The] posting [of] lame memes, photos and jokes is not going to make you funny."

So it's a referring to a singular act.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fact that you are posting contents (memes, photos and jokes). As soon as it's one action, you'd use "IS".

Comment: A lot of participants are vs.  The number of participants is..... (?) - Here, subject is similar, and still...?

Comment: @RamPillai depends... If you are talking about and action that all participants are doing together, for example "to eat", you'd say: "A lot of participants are eating french fries". In the second sentence, where you "reduced" the participants to a number, so you'd say: "the number of participants is 23".